# Typeahead get value and use that in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, typeahead.js

I am using jQuery [typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/) plugin for ajax search. Here in the demo you can see all the source data are linked to a json file and from that json file data are fetching. But in my case I have a php file as source and in the php file I am converting the matching data into json format with json_encode function. So can someone can tell me how to send the value to the php file where I will fetch the data from database and convert that in json format. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to fetch the data from server

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file, where you are echoing the json data,

Use

```
array('data' => single dimensional array of elements.)
```

And then json_encode() it.

In your file, where you are feeding it to the search, use $.ajax call.

Comment: I want to get the input search value in my ajax php file. How to get that value?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, every thing else is explained in typehead link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** to fetch the data from server
Try this,

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"page.php",
    success: function(data){
       // response "data" should be json from the server
       $("#dropdown").html(data);                
    }
});
```

Comment: I know that but I want to use typeahead.js for autocomplete